# Two menus show up

Tags: php, menus

If I set 'echo' parameters value to 'true':

```
<?php if( has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) {
                    wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters = array( 
                        'theme_location'  => 'primary-menu',
                        'container'       => '', 
                        'container_class' => false,
                        'container_id'    => false,
                        'menu'            => 'Primary',
                        'menu_id'         => 'test',
                        'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
                        'echo'            => true,
                        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                        'before'          => '',
                        'after'           => '',
                        'link_before'     => '',
                        'link_after'      => '',
                        'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
                        'depth'           => 0,
                        'walker'          => ''

                        ) ); 

                    wp_nav_menu (array('theme_location' => 'primary-menu'));

                    } ?>
```

I get an output of:

```
<ul id="test" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
 <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/test/">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://localhost/test/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="menu-primary" class="menu">
 <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/test/">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://localhost/test/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

The first one is the desired result and the last one is WP default output which is a pain. Any ideas on how to get rid of it by altering my array?

Comment: because you are calling "wp_nav_menu" two times.

Comment: Aargh, it's time for a break. Thank you @M-R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two calls to wp_nav_menu function

```
<?php if( has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) {
    wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters = array( 
        'theme_location'  => 'primary-menu',
        'container'       => '', 
        'container_class' => false,
        'container_id'    => false,
        'menu'            => 'Primary',
        'menu_id'         => 'test',
        'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => ''

        ) ); 

    // Following is outputing second menu html
    //wp_nav_menu (array('theme_location' => 'primary-menu'));

} ?>
```